# SQL query to see events leading to uninstall but no result

Tags: android, sql, google-bigquery

I tried to run this query and it's valid but returned 0kb:

```
SELECT eventName1, eventName2, eventName3, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM (
SELECT userProp.value.string_value AS accountID, app_info.firebase_app_id AS appInstanceID, event_timestamp AS eventTimestamp, event_name AS eventName1,
    LAG ( event_name, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY app_info.firebase_app_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) AS eventName2,
    LAG ( event_name, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY app_info.firebase_app_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) AS eventName3
  FROM `app_name.app_events_20180303*`, UNNEST(user_properties) AS userProp, UNNEST(event_params) AS eventParams
  WHERE ( eventParams.value.string_value = "app" OR event_name = "app_remove") AND userProp.key = "account_id"
  ORDER BY appInstanceID, eventTimestamp)
 WHERE eventName3 = "app_remove"
 GROUP BY eventName1, eventName2, eventName3
 ORDER BY count DESC
```

BigQuery displays "This query will process 16 MB when run", but Query returned zero record.

Ideally, I would like to see the result in a table with 2 events leading to uninstall event like what is shown in the image below:

[Big Query for 2 events before Uninstall event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6FEZ.png)

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting, what is the actual result vs the expected result?

Comment: @SimonPrice the error is no result despite it being a valid query. I expected to get a table of 3 columns of events and 1 column of account ids.

Comment: what happens when you run the query outside of the environment where you expect the result but get nothing?

Comment: I think your table shards are incorrect.  You use `20180303` which should be for 'March 3, 2018'.  Your `_TABLE_SUFFIX` criteria will be looking for shards between `2018030301' and '2018030310`.  If your goal is to get 10 days worth of data (Mar 1 - Mar 10), change your from to `_201803*`

Comment: @rtenha do you mean to change 'BETWEEN '01' AND '10'' to 'BETWEEN '_201803*' AND '_201803*'? I hope to get 1 day worth of data, on  March 3, 2018.

Comment: No.  Why do you have `_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '01' AND '10'`?  In essence, you are searching for tables that end in `2018030301`, `2018030302`, ..., `2018030310`.  Those are not dates, and thus are not valid table names, which is why your query processes 0B.  If you only need 1 day of data, just specify that in your table name `app_events_20180303`, no need for the `_TABLE_SUFFIX`.

Comment: @rtenha thank you for the suggestion! I tried to remove _TABLE_SUFFIX and it worked. The query will process 15MB when run but somehow the query returned no result... am I missing something out when I run the query?

Comment: Generally an empty results set means your filters don't capture the logic as intended. Even without knowing your tables/data, a few things stick out.  In the inner query, you are filtering for `app_remove` as `eventName1` (ignoring the `or` for now), and then in your outer query are filtering for `eventName3 = 'app_remove'`.  It seems unlikely that you will get many where both `eventName1` and `eventName3` are both `app_remove`.  2nd, I would probably restructure your query a bit to find the `app_remove` events first, and then get the 2 preceding events with `LAG` instead of `LEAD`

Comment: @rtenha Ideally I would like to see 3 columns in a table which will show the last 2 events leading to uninstall event. What I want to see is this table - https://miro.medium.com/max/2500/1*iIbr1g7QQZ8p2Yjh92Jg4Q.png. Would you be able to help me with this query?

Comment: can't see your image.  consider editing your original post and including your desired output there.  As much source data and expected output you can post is generally helpful on SO.